# Where are the sound files for pressure plate activations/button presses?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So, I've seen someone post this somewhere else and the answer was from somebody who didn't see the part "bedrock edition" apparently cause they just stated the answer for java lol.

I want to make a silent pressure plate but I just can't find the name of the sound for pressing a button and stepping on a pressure plate in bedrock edition. Its not `random.click` that's something else. Any help please? I guess its also the lever sound so I'm so lost.

I tried b`lock.wooden_pressure_plate.click` or whatever and it doesn't work, I also found on the bedrock sound list that sound `block.wooden_pressure_plate.click` doesn't even exist, it only exists on java.

Comment: Please limit it to one question per post! I know it was a side thing but I just removed it. If you'd like you can ask another question, but I'd recommend giving more detail because if you put that alone it would likely be closed as "needs more detail or clarity."

Comment: Yeah sorry, I looked at the rules and to me and they kinda made it seem like 2 is ok, the way they worded sounded like they were implying that you shouldn't have a lot of questions in one. So I thought I could do 2.

Answer (score 2):

Both buttons and pressure plates use the file sound.ogg, but for pressure plates the sound is warped.
https://www.minecraftforum.net

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).